# Oghma Infinium trick not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't know why but that glitch for the infinite level ups with the Oghma Infinium is not working. I searched it up and did every step right but it still won't let me read it again. What might be preventing it from working?

Comment: Do you have any mods or expansion packs installed? This glitch has been fixed in a variety of different ways e.g. the Unofficial Skyrim Patch, and an official patch too.

Comment: No i have no mods or patches and i think i got an older version because i got mine in 2012-13

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, the Oghma exploit was fixed a while ago (I think 1.9). You can check to see if you have the 1.9 patch by going to settings and switching your difficulty; in 1.9 Bethesda added Legendary difficulty and the ability to reset and make your skills Legendary as well once you get them to 100.

However the Alchemy/Enchanting loop exploit is still alive and game-breaking.

[If you must...](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=122671215)

Comment: I might have that version because i can make skills legendary i know know about the legendary difficult i can't check right this movement but what are the alchemy and enchanting loops

Comment: @jason Check the link at the end, it provides a very detailed guide.

Comment: What benefits does making your skills legendary have?

Comment: @jasonvalderrama that's another question, but it basically resets your skill level to 15, so you can level it up again, and thus level up yourself and gain more skillpoints that way.

Comment: oh ok thanks and i do have that version of skyrim or a better one